# Задать расположение flex элемента по центру

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно задать расположение одного flex элемента по центру, а другого оставить у правого края?
[image: Расположение элементов]
Сейчас у меня заданы следующие свойства:

```
<div class="box">
  <button class="button button1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 10px;
}

.button1 {
  justify-items: center;
}
```

Я попробовал задать для button1 свойство justify-items: center, чтобы выровнять его по центру, однако оно не сработало.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  width: 78px; /* width button */
}

.button1,
.button2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button class="button button1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем псевдоэлемент?

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `justify-items` задает выравнивание по умолчанию для всех **дочерних** блоков по необходимой оси.

Т.е он должен задаваться родительскому блоку, для выравнивания дочерних элементов, а вы задаете его кнопке (дочернему элементу), ожидая, что он отцентруется по центру.

Подробнее про это свойство (с интерактивными примерами) можете посмотреть вот тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items

Один из примеров реализации вашей задумки (не завязан на ширине кнопок):

```
.box {
  display: flex;
}

.button1 {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Т.к `margin-left: 50%;` смещает кнопку в центр относительно его левой стороны, то необходимо с помощью `transform` сместить ее по оси X левее (50% это половина ширины кнопки), чтобы кнопка разместилась ровно по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую "button 1" дать свойство justify-self со значением center

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self